# How to separate subscription and common checkout webhook in stripe?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I have made a webhook (flask) for stripe.

My app has both one time payment and subscription.

I would like to know how can I detect if it's normal checkout or subscription?

This is how I am separating now, but I think it's not recommended way.

I am checking stripe_subscription_id and if exist, I considered it as subscription.

(charge.succeeded is called for subscription succeeded also)

```
@api.route('/stripe/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    event = None
    payload = request.data

    try:
        event = json.loads(payload)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Webhook error while parsing basic request.' + str(e))
    if not event:
        return jsonify({'status': 'failed'}), 400

    # one time payout
    if event['type'] == 'charge.succeeded':
        event_intent = event['data']['object']
        payment_intent = event_intent['payment_intent']
    # payment
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        checkout_session = event['data']['object']

        stripe_subscription_id = checkout_session['subscription']
        # customer_email = checkout_session['customer_email']
        if stripe_subscription_id:
            # Create a new subscription and mark it as paid this month.
            customer_subscription_mark_paid(checkout_session['id'], stripe_subscription_id)
    elif event['type'] == 'invoice.paid':
        invoice = event['data']['object']
        stripe_subscription_id = invoice['subscription']
        if stripe_subscription_id:
            # Check if this is the first invoice or a later invoice in the
            # subscription lifecycle.
            first_invoice = invoice['billing_reason'] == 'subscription_create'

            # You already handle marking the first invoice as paid in the
            # `checkout.session.completed` handler.
            # Only use this for the 2nd invoice and later, so it doesn't conflict.
            if not first_invoice:
                # Mark the subscription as paid.
                customer_subscription_mark_paid(None, stripe_subscription_id)
    elif event['type'] == 'invoice.payment_failed':

        invoice = event['data']['object']
        stripe_subscription_id = invoice['subscription']

        if stripe_subscription_id:
            customer_subscription_mark_past_due(None, stripe_subscription_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking to see if the `subscription` field is filled is fine, but to be extra sure you can check the contents of the `mode` [field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-mode).